# Setting a Point with an X Location and a Angle in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, angle

I currently have code that takes in an X and Y location on a Cartesian Coordinate system and moves a point around.

However, I'd like to be able to accomplish the same action with only an X location taken in and a (Y) angle.

For example, if the code takes in (2,2) it moves the point from (0,0,0) to (2,2,0) successfully. I'd prefer to take in (2, 45°) and have the point move to the appropriate location.

Now I have an idea that to accomplish this I must first move the point along the X-axis. Then Rotate it around (0,0,0) by 45 degrees, however the process of accomplishing this second part has proven difficult to do and to research as I lack knowledge of the proper math terminology.

Any assistance would be very welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply dealing with right triangle and your task is to find an opposite side with given angle and another side. Use cos and sin of angle and x coordinate to find unknown side after. sin(angle) = y/vector, cos(angle) = x/vector. Then you can set your point with x,y.

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much for the great explanation. Just to make sure I'm a 100% following, when you write "...y/vector) are you referring to the y value of the points transform.position (Vector3)? Or is that expressly divide y by a value?

Comment: vector variable introduced here to find y coordinate with known x(2 in your example) and angle(45° in your example). once you found vector using cos formula, you substitute vector in sin and obtain y. With x and y you set your new point position. Note that when you find y its y of previous point + y (regarding your example its 0 + 2).

Comment: Oh! I think I see. So since I have the x as a known value. To get my Y point I would use the formula y = 45°/cos(2)?

Comment: To get your Y coordinate you would use y = 2*Sin(45°)/Cos(45°) and your y = 2(assuming your reference point y = 0)

Comment: Thank you for your patience and explanations. I understand the process now, which so much more than understanding only the implementation!

Comment: @VanDroid glad to be of help:)